# CodeIgniter - UserAgent

Tags: codeigniter, user-agent

I have the below code to check if the user is coming from a mobile, if they are I want to load a different page but it doesn't seem to be working...

Can anyone shed any light on the below:

```
if($xmlRefresh==1) {
   $viewData['content'] = $this->load->view('newquote/policy_xml', $viewData); 
   $this->load->view('layout', $viewData);

   } elseif ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {

      $this->_showPage("newquote/policy_mobile", 'Customise', $viewData); 

   } else {

      $this->_showPage("newquote/policy", 'Customise', $viewData); 

   }
```

I keep getting an internal server error, can anyone spot the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `system/core/Loader.php`, `function view()` that will be `$this->load->view` returns `void` unless you add third parameter. try with:

```
$viewData2['content'] = $this->load->view('newquote/policy_xml', $viewData1, TRUE);
```

and

```
 '''
 $this->_showPage("newquote/policy_mobile", 'Customise', $viewData2);
```

Note: `$viewData2` is different with `$viewData1`

Comment: Hi Charlie,

Thanks for the response, just looking at an If statement that I though't was working isn't working...

It just defaults to the mobile page, do you know of any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

are you calling this in controller?

What is the 500 (internal server) error??

Did you load the library user_agent??

```
$this->load->library('user_agent');


  if($xmlRefresh==1) {
   $viewData['content'] = $this->load->view('newquote/policy_xml', $viewData); 
   $this->load->view('layout', $viewData);

   } elseif ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {

      $this->_showPage("newquote/policy_mobile", 'Customise', $viewData); 

   } else {

      $this->_showPage("newquote/policy", 'Customise', $viewData); 

   }
```

Finally if you want serve the mobile pages, use [post post or pre hooks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html) to determine the user agent before view is executed (if you want to play around)

Comment: Yep, calling it in the controller...

Yep loaded the useragent at he top/ :-)

Comment: @ScottBaxter so what is the internal server error you are having?

Answer (score 0):

i have one idea, may be help u

you can replace redirect()/$this->load->view() to $this->_showPage("newquote/policy_mobile", 'Customise', $viewData);